# Artisan migration rename migration file error on migration:rollback

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I like to use artisan migrate to rollback an migration. But when i excecute:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

I get the following error message:
[image]

I have renamed the file, for reordering, befor I did the migration. In migration database is the correct file listed 2015_07_10_000007_create_einlagerungen_table.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `composer dump-autoload` if you have renamed the file so that composer can find it.